# Send string array to controller - MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about a project that I have been doing.
I try to do a simple mathematical exercise, where you have the numbers and the operation that must be done, and my program has to dynamically create the text box for the user, this because there will be cases where the result is with a length of 3 numbers or 2, my problem is that I have a model like this:

```
public class Sum
{
    public string num1 { get; set; }
    public string num2 { get; set; }
    public string[] numbers { get; set; }
    public int textBox { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a model who has that class like this:

```
public class Operations
{
    public Sum sum { get; set; }
    public Subtraction sub { get; set; }
    public string operation { get; set; }
    public string count { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my controller when the user clicks on the link "Exercises", I have this method:

```
public ActionResult Exercises()
{
    Ejercicios_Primero objeto = new Ejercicios_Primero();
    string numero = objeto.numeros(75, 0, 100);
    string numero2 = objeto.numeros(20, 0, 100);
    string count = "1";
    int textBox = ((int.Parse(numero) + int.Parse(numero2)).ToString()).Length;
    return View(new Operations { operation = "sum", sum = new Sum { num1 = numero, num2 = "0" + numero2, textBox = textBox }, count = count });
}
```

The paremeter textBox is to know how much TextBox i'm gonna create on the form, i have a code like this in javascript:

```
<script>

createInputs = function () {
    var input = $('<input />').attr("type", "textbox").attr("name", "numbers");
    return input;
}

$(function () {
    var boxes = eval('@Model.sum.textBox');
    if (boxes != null) {
        $('#boxes').html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < boxes; i++){
            $('#boxes').append(createInputs());
        }
    }
})
```

**As a result, I have something like this**

[image]

The parameter operation is for the controller to know what method use when receives a model of type "Operations", I have the next code in my controller with a model as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult Exercises(Operations model)
{
    Respuesta check = new Respuesta();

    switch (model.operation)
    {
        case "sum":
            string message = "";
            if (model.sum.numbers != null)
            {
                foreach (string inputValue in model.sum.numbers)
                {
                    message += inputValue + "\\n";
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("", message);
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Numbers is null");
                return View(model);
            }
        case "sub":
            check = Resta(int.Parse(model.sub.num1), int.Parse(model.sub.num2), int.Parse(model.sub.res1), int.Parse(model.sub.res2));
            if (!check.state)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", check.message);
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                Operations model2 = new Operations();
                Ejercicios_Primero objeto = new Ejercicios_Primero();
                string numero = objeto.numeros(75, 0, 100);
                model2.operation = "sum";
                model2.sum = new Sum();
                model2.sum.num1 = numero;
                numero = objeto.numeros(20, 0, 100);
                model2.sum.num2 = "0" + numero;
                return View(model2);
            }
    }
    return View();
}
```

The variable check in this case, it doesn't matter, the problem that I have is when I receive the model and I try to access the data, my model.sum.numbers is completely empty and I don't know why I did the javascript base on this page: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Dynamic-TextBox-controls-with-Add-Remove-Button-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx.

Note: I know that I'm not doing anything with the array, it's just for testing.

Comment: Your creating a `name="numbers"` attribute, but `Operations` does not contains a property named `numbers` - its contains a property named `sum` which contains a property named `numbers`, therefore your controls must be `name="sum.numbers"`

Comment: Wow,  i didn't even pay attention to that, now it works, thank you so much  Stephen.